# Memory allocation in Microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, c

I know I'm asking a basic Question. But it will be very useful for me to continue my Micro-controller Experience. Consider I am using a controller with 256 KB  Flash and 8 KB Ram. My Questions are

1. I know about memory mapping like code, Data, Stack and Heap Segment, which variable will store in which segment. But are these allocated in RAM or Flash
2. If I am declaring a buffer, I know it is allocating in RAM. Whether it will deallocate after the function ends (if that Buffer is Locally declared)
3. Where the Register Variable will allocate the memory.

Comment: Your questions are much better suited for stackoverflow, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Dzarda It's a bit of a grey area. While some of it is general programming theory, some (like what goes in flash and what in RAM) is more MCU specific, so fits here.

Comment: @Cool_Binami Can you explain what you mean in part 3?

Comment: @Majenko I think he means the `register` keyword.

Comment: @Dzarda He might mean SFRs though.  Clarification is needed.

Comment: @Majenko I mean Keyword register

Comment: @Cool_Binami Ok, I have added to my answer.

Comment: The register keyword was never more than a hint to the compiler, and is ignored by (almost?) all modern C / C++ compilers.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: I know VCC ignores `inline` and `register` except semantically, and I know that Clang takes `inline` into consideration", but I don't know what Clang does with `register`, or what GCC does with either.

Comment: As I indicated, they both ignore 'register'. You might as well have a '#define register' line at the start of your file. I don't know about inline, I never use it.

Answer (score 15):

Everything is done in "sections".  Where a section goes depends on its use.  What gets put into a section, again, depends on its use.

In general you get two "data" sections - .data and .rodata.  .data is stored in RAM and is read-write.  .rodata is stored in Flash and is read-only.

Things that are "const" generally end up in .rodata.  Literals (string, numeric, etc) also end up in .rodata.

For instance, these would normally be stored in Flash:

```
const char *foo = "foo";
const int bar = 234;

"baz" (string literal)
```

These will be stored in RAM:

```
char foo[10];
int bar;
```

But then of course, it can be more MCU specific, especially when you get into Harvard (split RAM / Flash address spaces) architecture, where accessing data stored in Flash can be more of a special task and not done as normal variables.  For instance, the `const char *foo="foo";` would be copied into RAM for easy access during the initialization of the program.

When you allocate a variable of any size within a function, such as:

```
void func() {
    char mybuf[100];
}
```

the variable will be allocated as part of the stack (or an emulated stack-like system using static variables on MCUs with a limited hardware stack, such as low-end 8-bit PICs). As soon as you return from the function all the stack space is reclaimed.

However, if you allocate it using malloc():

```
void func() {
    char *mybuf = malloc(100);
}
```

it will be allocated on the heap, and it is your responsibility to reclaim that space using free().

The `register` keyword, as in:

```
int register foo;
```

will, if a register can be allocated, store the data purely within that allocated register. It will never touch RAM, and consequently it will run faster.  However, if a register cannot be allocated (they're all in use in the code) then the register keyword will be ignored and the variable allocated in RAM as per normal.  One thing to note:

```
char register *foo;
```

That will only hold the *pointer* to the data in a register, not the data itself.  The data itself will still be in RAM.

In general, though, the use of the `register` keyword is frowned upon since the compiler's optimizer usually does a better job, and using `register` can in fact cause other parts of your code to not be optimized as well and end up more complex than they would otherwise be.

Comment: As a sidenote: On the avr-gcc platform for example, both `.rodata` and `.data` reside in RAM and are automagically loaded from flash on startup - unless you specify a variable with the `PROGMEM` attribute.

Comment: @Dzarda Yes, because of the Harvard architecture I mentioned in paragraph 4. You have to use special functions / registers to gain access to it, so many systems also duplicate it in crt0 into RAM for ease of access.

Comment: There are many microprocessor architectures that provide very limited, if any, access to a hardware stack. On such processors, the compiler allocates automatic variables statically, using extensive call tree analysis to make sure that no conflicts occur. While this successfully emulates the behavior of a stack-based system under most circumstances, certain techniques, such as recursion, cannot be used.

Comment: @DaveTweed Agreed. I've enhanced it to mention that.

Comment: @Majenko i am still confuse. You mean say that, there are two memory segment. Both in RAM and Flash?. So we need to look the memory of RAM rather than Flash while programming?if so, then why Flash memory is more compare to RAM in all Micro-Controllers

Comment: I have added some examples for you to make it clearer.

Comment: There are other sections in addition to the "data" sections that Majenko described.  Most significant is the .text section, which contains the executable code and is typically stored in flash.  Microcontrollers have more flash than RAM because applications typically require more code than data.

Comment: `register` is indeed considered unnecessary these days but `volatile` keyword is still useful / relevant to indicate data which may change by some external means in between accesses - fro example, the contents of MCU's peripheral registers, variables changed by an interrupt service routine, that sort of thing.

Comment: I'd note that on a platform with 8KB of RAM, you're not going to have dynamic memory allocation.  Global variables, and `static` declarations in functions are allocated at compile time and assigned addresses in the RAM's address space, and you'll know immediately whether you've exhausted your available memory (i.e., the compile fails).  On embedded you also need to watch your stack -- limit recursion and use of `auto` (non-`static`) variables in your functions.

Comment: It is Possible to store Data/variable in Flash instead of RAM

Comment: Changing the value of a flash memory address requires a relatively complex erase and program sequence which makes flash impractical for variables. Constant (read-only) data can be stored in flash, but not variable data.

Comment: @tomlogic In 8KB dynamic memory is perfectly possible. Maybe not advisable, but perfectly possible.  It's often used for "static" dynamic allocation - things like linked lists that get built up at power-on but never deleted from.

Comment: @Majenko: A useful pattern is to have a LIFO-based heap, where freeing anything releases everything freed after it.  Not useful if anything calls `malloc` implicitly or explicitly, but quite handy in many situations where a device's behavior may need to switch among several different roles.

Comment: Just a thought but keywords are supposed to apply to the left of the declaration, e.g. 'char const *foo;' is a pointer on const char and 'char * const foo;' is a constant pointer on variable char. Are you certain 'char register *foo;' is a valid thing rather than 'char * register foo;' which would be a register pointer on RAM char?

Comment: `char * register foo;` = "error: expected unqualified-id before 'register'".  `char register *foo` = compiles cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

ARM memory mapping - The entire code(along with variable's ,code etc ) goes to ROM. Since this a read only memory and variables have to change, variables are in turn remapped into the RAM. So your RAM will be stack + global  variables + static variables + heap(if any dynamic memory allocation). Local variables within functions are allocated within the stack and deallocated after the function exits